# Need some help HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, shopify

When i add the following code in my product-liquid (shopify), the whole page is destroyed, changes font and the add to cart button changes shape...

the code is here:

```html
<div id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery" class="shopify-section product-icon-gallery">
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image3.png?v=1576699921">
      <label>Satisfait ou Remboursé </label>
    </div>    
    <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image1.png?v=1576699921">
      <label>Meilleur prix</label>
    </div>    
    <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image2.png?v=1576699921">
      <label>Paiement 100% sécurisé</label>
      
      <div id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery" class="shopify-section product-icon-gallery">

<link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0262/4493/9862/t/2/assets/colors.scss.css?1306" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />

<link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0262/4493/9862/t/2/assets/custom.scss.css?1306" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  />
      
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GA3X81KCUYE6&fbclid=IwAR1k8r3ChVl2jtj3a0yyOTEaYM2KpS1FEnPzilXOoABh1JowkY9eVaVyLgs)

( click on run to see it :) )

Comment: I'm new in development

Comment: Pretty sure it is affecting the other elements with the same class. I would suggest you to hire a Shopify developer to do the changes.

Comment: Please include code relvent to the question **in the question itself**, preferably as a [MCVE] don't make us go off site to help you.

Comment: You have multiple `</div>` tags missing and `shopify-section-product-icon-gallery` is not a unique ID. An ID is required to be unique and all closing tags are required, otherwise the below elements will not be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few `</div>` HTML tags.
Think of HTML as a stack - for each tag you put on, you need the equivalent closing tag (in this case, you have more `<div>` tags than `</div>` tags). There are a few cases where the closing tags are required (in your current code, your `<img>` and `<link>` tags don't need a closing tag).

Comment: Do not answer questions that do not supply their markup or code within the question and only supply a link to some third party. Such questions will be closed. Not all questions should be answered: [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Vote to close them instead.

Comment: Even with your recommendations, the code would still be invalid as `id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery"` appears twice.

Comment: @EGC - that is correct (it's still not valid HTML, due to duplicate HTML id's), however having multiple HTML id's does not destroy page layout as described in the question.

Comment: Of course, only the missing tag destroyed this layout, however [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127192) highlights the potential risks of using duplicate ID's and the obvious illegalities in greater detail. It's just worth discussing potential issues with code overall as well as providing an answer to the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing 3 closing div tags (`</div>`) at the end. This would cause shopify styles to be applied to everything after the code. add the 3 closing div tags and should be ok.

I have added a comment, See code below:

```
 <div id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery" class="shopify-section product-icon-gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image3.png?v=1576699921">
                    <label>Satisfait ou Remboursé </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image1.png?v=1576699921">
                    <label>Meilleur prix</label>
            </div>
            <div class="item " style="width: 33.333333333333336%">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/5884/2477/files/image2.png?v=1576699921">
                <label>Paiement 100% sécurisé</label>
                <div id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery" class="shopify-section product-icon-gallery">
                    <link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0262/4493/9862/t/2/assets/colors.scss.css?1306" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
                    <link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0262/4493/9862/t/2/assets/custom.scss.css?1306" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  />
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- You were missing the tags below -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not answer questions that do not supply their markup or code within the question and only supply a link to some third party. Such questions will be closed. Not all questions should be answered: [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Vote to close them instead.

Comment: This code is still invalid. `id="shopify-section-product-icon-gallery"` appears twice.